# Try statement syntax

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have been reading [python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#try) , could someone help me with interpreting this?

```
try_stmt  ::=  try1_stmt | try2_stmt
try1_stmt ::=  "try" ":" suite
               ("except" [expression [("as" | ",") identifier]] ":" suite)+
               ["else" ":" suite]
               ["finally" ":" suite]
try2_stmt ::=  "try" ":" suite
               "finally" ":" suite
```

I initially thought it meant that try statements had to have either formats

1. `try` And `finally` or
2. `try`, `except`, `else` AND `finally`.

But after reading the documentation, it mentioned that `else` is optional and so is `finally`. So, I was wondering what is the purpose of the documentation showing us the code in the above format to begin with?

Comment: The brackets mean optional. The parens on the `except` are used for grouping with the `+` (because the `except` can occur more than once in that form).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You **do** have two forms of the `try` statement. The main difference between them is that in the case of `try1_stmt` an `except` clause **must be specified**.

In **[Introduction | Notation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/introduction.html#notation)** of the Python Language reference, the following is written:

> *A star **(*) means zero or more repetitions** of the preceding
>   item; likewise, **a plus (+) means one or more repetitions**, and a phrase enclosed in square brackets **([ ]) means zero
>   or one occurrences** (in other words, the enclosed phrase is optional)* . The * and + operators bind as tightly as possible;
>   ***parentheses are used for grouping***.

So, specifically, in the first form:

```
try1_stmt ::=  "try" ":" suite
               ("except" [expression [("as" | ",") identifier]] ":" suite)+
               ["else" ":" suite]
               ["finally" ":" suite]
```

The `else` and `finally` clauses **are optional `([])`**, you only require a `try` statement and ***one*** or more `(+)` `except` clauses.

In the second form:

```
try2_stmt ::=  "try" ":" suite
               "finally" ":" suite
```

You **only** have a single `try` and a single `finally` clause with no `except` clauses.

---

Do note that for the first case the order of the else and finally clauses are fixed. An `else` clause *following* a `finally` clause results in a `SyntaxError`.

In the end of the day, this all boils down to essentially not being able to have a `try` clause together with **only** an `else` clause. So in code form these two are allowed:

First form of the try statement (**`try1_stmt`**):

```
try:
    x = 1/0
except ZeroDivisionError:
    print("I'm mandatory in this form of try")
    print("Handling ZeroDivisionError")
except NameError:
    print("I'm optional")
    print("Handling NameError")
else:
    print("I'm optional")
    print("I execute if no exception occured")
finally:
    print("I'm optional")
    print("I always execute no matter what")
```

Second form (**`try2_stmt`**):

```
try:
    x = 1/0
finally:
    print("I'm mandatory in this form of try")
    print("I always execute no matter what")
```

For an easy to read PEP on this subject, see **[PEP 341](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0341/)** which contains the original proposal for the two forms of the `try` statement.

Comment: Thanks alot. This explanation is very clear. Would you mind explaining what it means by as tightly as possible? "The * and + operators bind as tightly as possible"

Comment: I'm not 100% sure about this because lexical definitions is something I haven't been exposed to in depth. What I'm guessing this means is that it has a higher precedence, so, a rule like `a_rule ::= part1 | part2*` ( the `|` symbol means **or**) should be interpeted as `a_rule ::= part1 | (part2*)` and not as `a_rule ::= (part1 | part2)*`. I hope this makes some sense to you.